# How to set up mod_proxy_wstunnel on Apache 2.2 on CentOS

Tags: websocket, proxy, apache2.2

Is there a way to set up the `mod_proxy_wstunnel` module on Apache 2.2 on CentOS? I can't upgrade to 2.4 due to project limitations.

Answer (score 9):

I have invested lot of time figuring this out and there is very little documentation available for this. Let me know if this helps, else I can help you troubleshooting the problem. Also hope this helps to future readers.

To compile `mod_proxy_wstunnel.so`,

1. `yum install httpd-devel`
2. Download the `mod_proxy_wstunnel.c`
3. Compile it using, `apxs -i -a -c mod_proxy_wstunnel.c`

Now load the above compiled module in `/etc/httpd/modules`

1. Copy the `mod_proxy_wstunnel.so` in `/etc/httpd/modules` (Compiled from above)
2. In order to load the module while the server starts, use `LoadModule` directive in the httpd conf file, `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Add the following line with all other LoadModule line,

```
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
```

3. To restart apache, use `service httpd restart`
4. To check the loaded modules in apache after restarting use, `httpd -M`
5. After the module is installed, Add this two lines in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```
ProxyPass /websockets/mywebsocket ws://mywebsocketserver.com//websockets/mywebsocket retry=4  
ProxyPassReverse /websockets/mywebsocket ws://mywebsocketserver.com//websockets/mywebsocket retry=4
```

Note: Make sure the above lines are added before the default case of `/`. Also restart apache just to be safe.

Comment: Thanks it works. The source of the module is available here -  https://gist.github.com/bodgit/80a2fb09170596589a03